# Can I use the window object in the public folder to declare global variable and use it inside the src folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window

I want declare global variables in `public/config/current.js` using `window` object and get those variables inside `src/config/config.js`. the problem is those variable are always `undefined`.

this is my code:

`public/config/current.js`

```
window.ENV = {
    BACK_END_API_URL: 'http://localhost:9999/api'
    };
```

`src/config/config.js`

```
export const {
    BACK_END_API_URL = 'http://localhost:9998/api'
} = window.ENV;
```

`src/api/Employee.js`

```
import { BACK_END_API_URL } from '../config/config';
import { apiInstance } from './apiInstance';

const employee_api = apiInstance(`${BACK_END_API_URL}/v1/employees`)

export const getEmployeeByEmail = async (employeeEmail) =>  await employee_api.get(`/employee?email=${employeeEmail}`)
```

Comment: Where/when is `current.js` imported?

Comment: seems like a bad idea to add them to a global variable

Comment: I don't import `current.js` i use it just to declare my window variables